# How to bind selecteditem of wpf combobox with my.setting?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, combobox, binding, serial-port

I'm retriving the serialports and populate a combobox as this:

XAML

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="2"     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ComPorts, Mode = TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  SelectedValue="{Binding Path= myserialportx, Mode = TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="myserialportx"/>
```

VM

```
Private _comports As String()
    Public Property ComPorts() As String()
        Get
            Return System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String())
            _comports = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            SetAndNotify(_comports, value)

        End Set
    End Property

Private _myserialportx As String
Public Property myserialportx As String
        Get

            Return _myserialportx
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            My.Settings.comport = value
            SetAndNotify(_myserialportx, value)
        End Set
    End Property
```

I need to save the selected port in my.setting so user does not need to set it anytime, and then I would like to also "preselect" it as it can see what port is actually selected.
Any advice?

Comment: A few notes. `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=myserialportx ...}"` and `SelectedValuePath="myserialportx"` do not make sense together. Use `SelectedItem="{Binding myserialportx}"`. Setting `Mode=TwoWay` also makes no sense in both Bindings. The ItemsSource Binding is inherently OneWay, and the SelectedItem Binding is TwoWay by default. Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`is pointless in both.

Comment: I made the changes you suggest, but my.setting still not be update.

Comment: You mean it is not saved and restored when you restart the application?

Comment: yes, I also added  My.Settings.Save() and My.Settings.Reload() after  My.Settings.comport = value, but still not saved and restored.

Comment: Reload makes no sense there. Make sure that the comport setting has User scope. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object

Comment: I defined all has User scope.

Comment: Comport settimg Is userscope, but still not save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Seem that when in debug VS save setting in a file that is not the same you see in the editor, switching to release mode it actually work.